# @import google fonts displays incorrect

Tags: html, css, fonts

I trying to import google fonts
here is code:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&subset=latin,cyrillic);
```

and for different elements I using different `font-weight` property
300, 400, 600

but it isn't do that
what I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works correctly and no problem.

See this example on CodePen : http://codepen.io/mehrabi/pen/dGBrQN

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&subset=latin,cyrillic);

body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
.noStyleP{
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: noraml;
}
.p1{
  font-weight: 300;
}
.p2{
  font-weight: 400;
}
.p3{
  font-weight: 600;
}
.p4{
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not working, because you have typo-error:

Not `font-weigth`, but `font-weight`.

Answer (score -1):

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&subset=latin,cyrillic);
```

should be

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&subset=latin,cyrillic);
```

Sometimes the https:// does not work with google due to faulty ssl certificate.
Try that instead!!!

Comment: 300,400,600 and 400,300,600 as in your question it says that you asked for different values.

Comment: Not good answer because if you open the URLs in your browser you can see the CSS file, and there isn't any different in both file. Check different in 
[https://www.diffchecker.com/jymvgdk9](https://www.diffchecker.com/jymvgdk9)